# Que veut dire « à telle heure battant » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Voici une citation de « Madame Bovary »:

> À six heures battant vous allez le voir entrer [...].

Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?

J'ai moi-même une théorie, mais je peux bien avoir tort. Je soupçonne que ça veut dire « à six heures exactement », et le mot « battant » est utilisé parce que l'on bat les cloches des églises pour annoncer l'heure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans *[battant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/battant)<sup>1,2</sup>*:

> [subst. masc.]
>   **A.−** *TECHNOLOGIE*
>   1. Pièce métallique mobile suspendue à l'intérieur d'une cloche dont elle frappe et fait résonner la paroi :
>
> - La suggestion y naît irrésistiblement comme la vibration que le **battant** de la cloche imprime au bronze, dès qu'il le heurte. Huyghe, *Dialogue avec le visible*,1955, p. 220.

---

> [...]II.− Adjectif
>
> **A.−** Qui bat, qui frappe avec violence :
>   1. − Demain nous chasserons le chevreuil dit le marquis pendant la retraite qui se faisait par une pluie battante; ... La Hêtraie, *La
>   Chasse*, vén., fauconn.,1945, p. 190.
>
> − Loc. *À l'heure battante*. **À l'heure précise.**
>
> **ÉTYMOL. ET HIST.**
>
> [...]II.− Subst.[...] 2. 1380 « objet qui retombe en frappant » (Conty, *Prob.
>   d'Arist.*, B.N. 210, fo168 a dans Gdf. Compl. : Comme quant le *batent*
>   qui est de fer fiert la chose qui est de matiere sonnable) en partic.
>   1680 *battant de cloche* (Rich.)[.]
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* - TLFi ]

---

L'idée du coup répété a toujours été présente dans les sens de [*battre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/battre?idf=dmfXdXpcYbde;str=0); il y a aussi *battre une pièce de monnaie* par exemple, qu'on pourrait aussi faire sonner(comme une cloche si de bon métal).

D'autre part, *donner l'heure*, *l'heure convenue* et *l'horloge sonne l'heure* remontent au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle. Puis suivent l'heure *précise* avec *sonnant*(1690), *battant* ou *battantes*(1856) et *tapant*(20<sup>e</sup>) - selon ce qu'en dit le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sous. la dir. d'A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*). On note que [*sonnant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonnant) - « *[q]ui est en train de sonner exactement l'heure énoncée* » - apparaît avant *battant* pour l'heure; *sonner* dans le sens d'*annoncer par une sonnerie* serait du 12<sup>e</sup>, p. ex. *sonner une messe*. On définit aussi éventuellement la *montre sonnante* comme « *[p]ourvu d'un mécanisme qui sonne les heures (et les divisions d'heures), qui produit une sonnerie*. » On peut s'[amuser](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heures%20sonnant%2Cheures%20sonnantes%2Cheures%20tapant%2Cheures%20tapantes%2Cheures%20battant%2Csix%20heures%20sonnant%2Csix%20heures%20sonnantes%2Csix%20heures%20tapant%2Csix%20heures%20tapantes&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheures%20sonnant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheures%20sonnantes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheures%20tapant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheures%20tapantes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheures%20battant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csix%20heures%20sonnant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csix%20heures%20sonnantes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csix%20heures%20tapant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csix%20heures%20tapantes%3B%2Cc0) avec le corpus de livres de *Google* pour illustrer les emplois.

---

Il s'agit de l'*heure précise* (*à six heures précises*) et sans doute de l'action du battant ou du marteau battant contre la [cloche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cloche) qu'on [tire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tirer) ou sonne, et donc qui *sonne*. *Battre de la* cloche ferait référence à l'idée instrument assurément. Mais il me semblerait étrange d'entendre qu'une personne veut directement *battre* ou *faire battre* la cloche d'un clocher, qui plus est avec un marteau. Pas plus, au final, que de savoir qu'au son d'une cloche « battante », il pourrait être *minuit clochant*!!

Comment: Je voudrais vérifier que j'ai bien compris ce que vous avez dit dans le dernier paragraphe. J'ai écrit « l'on bat les cloches », mais c'est une erreur et ça ne veut pas dire ce que j'avais cru. J'aurais du écrire « l'on sonne les cloches » ou « l'on tire les cloches ». C'est ça ? Je veux être sûr. J'ai écrit « battre les cloches » sans réfléchir, c'est une traduction mot à mot d'une expression russe.

Comment: @dan19 Il faut noter de plus qu'on _fait sonner_ des cloches. La réponse est plus sur l'origine des différences entre battre, sonner etc. et les liens qui les unissent.

Comment: Merci, j'ai compris.

Comment: @dan19 Il n’y a pas de quoi! Merci!

Answer (score 4):

Je pense également que c'est de là que provient l'expression, d'autant qu'on lit aussi « à six heures frappantes » ou encore « à six heures sonnantes ».

Comment: C'est amusant, je n'ai jamais entendu ces variantes, mais exactement dans la même veine j'entends souvent *à six heures tapantes* (Nancy, Lorraine).

Comment: Oui, c'est probablement la variante la plus usitée. Il y a aussi, plus familier, "six heures pétantes".

Comment: Ah oui tu as raison, celle-ci aussi on l'entend parfois, bien trouvé.

Answer (score 4):

Effectivement synonyme de « à six heures exactement », d'après [ce dictionnaire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KOINHRkfU_oC&lpg=PA129&ots=5cmFQj8VqC&dq=%22heures%20battant%22&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q=%22heures%20battant%22&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

"À six heures pile" serait la version plus moderne.